# Creating instances of a class with different preset templates

Tags: c#, class, templates, object, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a app on C# Visual Studio '13, and I just hit a brickwall - a newbie brickwall I bet. I have a class - lets say it's a car class. It isn't, but it's a decent example for this question.

Now, I'd like to create - I'm not sure this is the right terminology - templates, from which I'd like to create instances. These created instances will be stored in a `List<Car>` object.

Let's just say the car class has name, model year and mileage attributes. I'd like to be able to create a template, where I can call up a constructor to create a car with a preset name and model year, but a randomized mileage - and have a couple of different ones. Maybe use it in a constructor in such a way, that I have a few sets of presets - or templates - e.g. '99 BMW, '03 Merc and a '79 Lada. When I call the constructor, I'd like it to pick one of these templates, and add a random mileage.

The adding random mileage is not a problem. Matter of fact, there is no problem with building this other than the fact that for the life of me, I can't figure out how to do templates in a constructor.

Comment: You don't 'do templates in the constructor', you write a CarFactory class. And maybe a CarTemplate class too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the easiest solutions for some hardcoded, predefined instance values is the [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). For the following `Car` class:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Model { get; private set; }
    public int Year { get; private set; }
    public Color Color { get; private set; }
    public int Mileage { get; private set; }

    // ...

    public Car(string model, int year, Color color, int mileage)
    {
        Model = model;
        Year = year;
        Color = color;
        Mileage = mileage;
    }
}
```

you can create `CarFactory` as suggested by [Henk Holterman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761/henk-holterman) in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29581349/creating-instances-of-a-class-with-different-preset-templates-in-c-sharp#comment47311024_29581349). For example:

```
public class CarFactory
{
    public CarFactory()
    {
        random = new Random();
    }

    public Car CreateBMW99WithRandomMileage(Color color)
    {
        return new Car("BMW", 1999, color, random.Next());
    }

    public Car Create03BlackMerc(int mileage)
    {
        return new Car("Mercedes", 2003, Colors.Black, mileage);
    }

    public Car Create79Lada(Color color, int mileage)
    {
        return new Car("Lada", 1979, color, mileage);
    }

    // ...

    private Random random;
}
```

As you can see you have many possibilities when choosing which attributes to fix, which should be random, and which can be left out as configurable.

Another, similar, pattern you can employ here is the [prototype pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern).

Here is how you can combine these two patterns to create a random car:

```
public class CarFactory
{
    public CarFactory()
    {
        random = new Random();
        black99BMW = new Car("BMW", 1999, Colors.Black, 0);
        black03Merc = new Car("Mercedes", 2003, Colors.Black, 0); 
        black79Lada = new Car("Lada", 1979, Colors.Black, 0);

        // ...

        allCars = new Car[] { black99BMW, black03Merc, black79Lada };
    }

    public Car CreateBMW99WithRandomMileage(Color color)
    {
        return black99BMW.Clone(color, random.Next());
    }

    public Car Create03BlackMerc(int mileage)
    {
        return black03Merc.Clone(Colors.Black, random.Next());
    }

    public Car Create79Lada(Color color, int mileage)
    {
        return black79Lada.Clone(color, mileage);
    }

    public Car CreateRandomCar()
    {
        var index = random.Next(allCars.Length);
        Color color = // pick random color
        int mileage = random.Next();

        return allCars[index].Clone(color, mileage);
    }

    private Car black99BMW;
    private Car black03Merc; 
    private Car black79Lada;
    private Car[] allCars;
}
```

Possibilities are countless - this is just a simple example, and does not necessary fit your scenario best. However, usually and especially for beginners, it is better to implement something to see how does it work, to see its advantages and flaws with your own eyes, and then try to improve it.

Comment: Thanks for a speedy answer. It seems i was thinking about the problem in a backwards way - instead of the obvious way of using constructors with fixed and random attributes.

The final part I'm missing is how can i randomize which car the CarFactory creates? If i put it in game terms: There's a random encounter, where the player finds one of the the three cars in the CarFactory object.

I appreciate your help, even though i constantly feel like I'm just missing something obvious.

Comment: Oh man, arrays. Of course. Should have known it's something obvious. I do very much appreciate the time you took to answer this nevertheless.